# Tychonoff spaces are perfect images of extremally disconnected spaces.

Tags: general-topology

[Encyclopaedia of Mathematics](http://books.google.com/books?id=1ttmCRCerVUC&pg=PA524&lpg=PA524&dq=every+completely+regular+space+is+perfect+image+of+even+extremally+disconnected+space&source=bl&ots=XkBRh9aU_K&sig=OzD1lhP2-b8eNbwksi9mWDb9Gaw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DHFvUa2ILbO44AOf_4D4Cg&sqi=2&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=every%20completely%20regular%20space%20is%20perfect%20image%20of%20even%20extremally%20disconnected%20space&f=false), p524, says that

> **Completely regular spaces are perfect images of extremally disconnected spaces**.

But no process and no reference has been presented to prove. Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s you again. :-) It seems that we already can prove the claim. Let $X$ be a completely regular space, $bX$ be a compactification of $X$, and $X_\delta$ be the set $X$ endowed with the discrete topology. By [En, Th. 3.6.1] there exists a continuous extension $f:\beta X_\delta\to bX$ be of the identity map $X_\delta \to X$. Put $Y=f^{-1}(X)$. Since $Y\supset X_\delta$, we see that $Y$ is dense in $\beta X_\delta$. Hence the space $Y$ should be extremally disconnected as a dense subspace of an extremally disconnected space $\beta X_\delta$. Since $f$ is perfect, [En, Prop. 3.7.4] implies that the restriction $f_{X}:f^{-1}(X)\to X$ is perfect too.

*References*

[En] Ryszard Engelking “General topology” (Russian Edition)

Comment: Oops. :-( I rewrote my answer.